What is expanding and contracting in LIGO? The space between the arms, the arms themselves, or both?
At LIGO, gravitational waves are detected by the interference effects of the laserlight traveling in the mutually orthogonal arms.
But what is actually expanding and contracting? Are the arms themselves expanding? It's clear that the space is expanding and contracting, and it seems that if the metric of the arms varies in the same way as the metric of the space inside them that no interference effect is seen at all.
So, what's going on? Do the arms retain their shape, while the space inside them expands and contracts? Or do both occur? For sure the arms can't expand and contract like space itself contracts. So, what's actually going on?

LIGO measures the path length of light travelling between its test masses. The experiment is built in such a way that the motion of the test masses (in the direction of the light path) is (almost) completely decoupled from the structures they are housed in. It is this path length that is changing with time.
This can be interpreted as being due to the test masses moving under influence of the passing gravitational wave or the space between the test masses contracting and expanding. General relativity, however, does not really distinguish between these two interpretations, which are just different "gauge" choices from the p.o.v. of the theory, hence the term relativity.

You don't really need the curved space picture to understand LIGO.
In the presence of a gravitational wave two masses that normally hang straight down towards the centre of the earth feel slightly different gravitational acceleration. This is effectively a time-dependent tidal force. If they were separated by initial distance $l$ then these different forces cause their separation to change $l\to l+ x(t)$ where
$$
 \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =- c^2 l R_{1010}
 $$
(or also $R_{1020}$ for  the other polarization) so  the curvature tensor component $ R_{1010}$ has the physical  interpretation as the difference of the $x$ component of ${\bf g}$ force per unit separation in the $x$ direction.
For small amplitude waves the tidal force   at distance $r$ from the source is
$$
  R_{\alpha0\beta0} = \frac{G}{3c^6}\frac 1 r \frac{d^4}{dt^4} D_{\alpha\beta}
  $$
where $D_{\alpha\beta}$ is the quadrupole moment of the distant source.
You can might be tempted  think that the $x$ is simply  the space itself changing the distance due to the change in the metric.
Consider, for example, a small-amplitude gravitational plane wave in which
$$
ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 -dx^2-(1-a)dy^2- (1+a) dz^2 +2b dydz
$$
with $a(t-x)$, $b(t-x)$ so that the wave is propagating in the $x$ direction. You can compute the $R_{\alpha0\beta0}$ and find that   for free particles
$$
\ddot x=0\nonumber\\
\ddot y =  -\frac 12 (\ddot a y+ \ddot b z)\nonumber\\
\ddot z= -\frac 12 (\ddot b y- \ddot a z),\nonumber
$$
which is tantalizingly close to regarding $y$ or $z$ as the integrated change in the distance given by the metric. But now you have to ask yourself about the effect on the lightwaves that are being used to see that the effects don't cancel each other.
A clear advantage of the "force" interpretation  is to be seen, however, if you consider finite-length  pulses of radiation.  With $F_y= - \frac 12 \ddot ay$ you can see that for a general finite pulse there is no reason for $I=\int_{\rm pulse} F_ydt$ to be zero. So, even after the pulse is over and $a=b=0$, the free particles may be left with a residual velocity or displacement. As the space is now back to the standard measure of distance this memory effect cannot be interpreted  as a mere geometric change in the distance between the particles.
